# Can you change language of javascript error event messages?

Tags: javascript

In our webapp we log messages to the server via window.onerror

However, if the client (the web browser) is using a non english language the message will be in whatever language the user has their web browser set to.

Is there any way to change this somehow?

Currently it is very unhelpful to get messages in multiple languages, hard to search for similar errors when they are in 12 different languages, also tricky for developers that need to translate to english all the time to figure out what went wrong.

[Edit] Adding an example here

```
window.onerror = function (message, url, lineNumber, columnNumber) {
    // log error here to server
}
```

In this example, the message will be in english most of the time, but sometimes it turns up in for example danish or swedish depending on the client (webbrowser).

Comment: I might be missing something here, but isn't it always in english? I mean, clearly not, as you're receiving different languages, but I have my browser in italian at home and in german at work, and in both cases I see my console errors in english..

Comment: The answer to this might be different depending on which browser is being used at the time.

Comment: Adding a concrete example will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **you cannot change it**. The message is a descriptive message because of an error code. Your web app **should** take into consideration only the state (code) of the error, not the message.

These messages are part of your browser settings, which you will not have rights to change (some of them are read-only, but **all** are write-protected). This could mean I can render a user's browser useless by changing the program settings from javascript (for example, changing the language to Japanese for an english-only user :).

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable. The followup is: how do I get this error code?
 All I can find, looking for example at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror
is Message, Url, LineNumber and Column. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that can be solved by determining Error types. See "Error Types" section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: @kuzzmi Thanks, I will add some code that checks the type of the error, that should give some more details.